# How to send email using server's IP Address

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, smtp

I have an **SMTP Server** , 
Then I have a **Main Server** - where my C# Windows application was deployed thru IIS.
Only **Main server** has access to the **SMTP Server**.
Problem is :

After I have deployed the Application to the Main Server , then as I downloaded the Application thru the link, every time it send email , it prompts :

*A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond*

How can I send email using the **Main Server's** *IP Address* ? since it's the only address the **SMTP Server** recognise ? Thank you

Comment: When I understand right, you deployed your application like a setup to the main server and then you download it and run it from a different machine. That would not work. If only the main server has access to the SMTP server you will need code executed on the main server (e.g. a service, a web application, etc) to send email to the SMTP server.

Comment: Yes you understand it right , so  really needed a service ? But the Application I downloaded was from the server ? does it not use the server's credentials ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response Mr. H.G. Sandhagen :) , very much appreciated your help! :)

Comment: "Application I downloaded was from the server ? does it not use the server's credentials ?" If that were so, this would mean the immediate death of the internet.